# WSO2 Identity Server connectivity with APIM for User Management

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are trying to **establish connectivity between WSO2 APIM and WSO2 Identity server**, so that we can **use Identity Server for User Management on top of APIM**.

We have gone through almost all documentation available on the website.

Also went through the documentation of "Using WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager with APIM", but found it insufficient.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/install-and-setup/deploying-wso2-api-manager/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/

**Expected Flow:**

1. A user account should be created using Identity Server.
2. After account creation, user should be able to login.
3. After successful login, user should be redirected to APIM publisher or devportal.
4. Admin user should be able to control the API access of registered users.

**Is there any specific document available which describes the steps to perform connectivity between APIM and Identity Server?**

or

**What is the correct way to achieve this?**

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you said `user account` did you mean application developers who subscribe to APIs or the end-users who call APIs (after logged into some app)?

Comment: 'User account' implies that I want to give an external user access to the Devportal only, where the user can subscribe to any API and also should be able to access the API form postman.

Comment: Could you achieved? I couldn't find any tutorial explaining how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement should be achieved via configuring IS as Key manager

[https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/][1]

- You need to configure central userstore for WSO2 IS and APIM.
- You can register a user via self registration feature or Add user feature in WSO2 Identity server.
- Then the created user should assign publisher and store roles to access the publisher and store portals.

  - Once you configure portal as a service provider in IS-KM, you can login to store and publisher via that created user.
    https://medium.com/@naduni_pamudika/enabling-sso-for-wso2-apim-3-0-0-e9421fed0d13

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/extensions/saml2-sso/configuring-identity-server-as-idp-for-sso/#configuring-wso2-api-manager-as-service-provider-for-identity-server